# C++ Square root / Babylonian method?

Tags: c++, math

i found this method to calculate the square root in a youtube video, but I could not understand the mathematical concept behind it, the code works perfectly, can anyone explain to me what happens in this code?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

float estimation = 1, num;

cout << " input :";
cin >> num;

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    estimation = (estimation + (num / estimation)) / 2;
}

cout << estimation << '\n';

return 0;
}
```

link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBaj1kQJYeU

Comment: Don't spam tags! C is not C++!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just the Babylonian method for estimating square roots:

https://www.deltacollege.edu/dept/basicmath/Babylonian.htm

> **Babylonian Square Roots**
>
> Step 1: Make a guess.
>
> Step 2: Divide your original number by your guess.
>
> Step 3: Find the average of these numbers.
>
> Step 4: Use this average as your next guess.

In the code above:

Step 1 (the number to estimate the square root for) is taken as input from the user, and stored in `num`. The `estimation` is `1` in this case:

```
cin >> num;
```

Step 2 and Step 3 together:

```
estimation = (estimation + (num / estimation)) / 2;
```

Step 4:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    // ...
}
```

In this case the process is repeated 20 times.

Also, instead of always taking the `estimation` as `1`, it would be better if it were instead set to `num/2` for a closer estimate.

Answer (score 2):

This is the Newton method for `f(x)=x²-a` in that

```
N(x) = x - f(x)/f'(x) = x - (x²-a)/(2x) = (x+a/x)/2
```

It is also helpful to calculate the quantity

```
( N(x) - sqrt(a) ) / (N(x) + sqrt(a) )
= ( x - sqrt(a) )² / ( x + sqrt(a) )²
```

which shows that the error in each step is about the square of the previous error, or as it is also expressed, the number of valid digits more or less doubles in every step.